# IOS resizableImageWithCapInsets not stretching

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am not sure how to calculate the insets for my messaging bubble. [image: Messaging Bubble]

Currently I set my insets to look like the following:
[image]

The code I am using is:

```
self.balloonView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ConvoBubbleWhite.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(45, 43, 8, 30)];
```

The problem is that the bubble is not stretching at all.

If I use:

```
self.balloonView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ConvoBubbleWhite.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)];
```

It will stretch but not stretch properly.

Here is what the bubble looks like on the device:

[image]

Please note that the bubble is the one on the left side of the screen.

Comment: Did you set the frame of `balloonView`?

Comment: Yes I did. I have played with the insets and it sometimes stretches horizontally and vertically but it doesn't stretch perfectly. Using the code I placed above (based on my understanding of insets), it should stretch perfectly but it doesn't stretch at all. I edited my question to reflect that observation.

Comment: Show the code where you set the view's frame. Show an image of the results.

Comment: This might or might not be your case. If the image is @2x remember to take use dimensions/2 (possibly 22.5,21.5,4.0,15.0)?

Comment: It looks like you're right. I should be dividing it by 2. I'm looking into that now. You should put your response as an answer so I can select it to be correct if it is right.

Comment: Hey rokjarc, it worked. Thanks for your help. I wish I can accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Glad it worked - I had similiar issue a month ago :) added an answer

Answer (score 0):

When you are using retina (@2x) images only make sure to account for scale 2.0.

Instead of

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(45, 43, 8, 30)
```

try with

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(22.5,21.5,4.0,15.0)
```